# When dropdown list item is selected button becomes clickable

Tags: java, php, html, button, drop-down-menu

Can you help me with the code of the following?

I have a drop-down list of items.

- Option-1
- Option-2
- Option-3
- Option-X

Below the drop-down list is a button that is initially inactive (grayed out)

Now when the user selects `Option-1`, `Option-2` *OR* `Option-3` the button becomes active and links to website-1.com when clicked.

But when the user selects `Option-X` the button becomes active and links to website-2.com when clicked.

Comment: *"Can you help me with the code"*  Sure, what do you have so far?  If the answer is 'nothing', it seems you don't so much want help as someone to write it for you.  That is not what SO is about.  BTW is this Java or PHP?  Do you use JSP or servlets (that would be Java)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Below Code... I believe you need `HTML/ Javascript` code

```
<html>
<script language="javascript">
var myLink = "";
function hideMe() {
    document.getElementById('btn3').style.visibility='hidden';
}
function setMyAdd() {
    location.href=myLink;
}
function checkForChange() {
    document.getElementById('btn1').style.visibility='visible';
    document.getElementById('btn2').style.visibility='visible';
    var buttonSelected=selList.value;
    // alert("Option Selected is : " + buttonSelected );
    if (buttonSelected=="optx") {
    myLink = "myPage2.html";
    document.getElementById('btn1').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('btn2').style.visibility='visible';
    document.getElementById('btn3').style.visibility='visible';
    } else {
    myLink = "myPage1.html";
    document.getElementById('btn1').style.visibility='visible';
    document.getElementById('btn2').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('btn3').style.visibility='visible';
    }
}
</script>
<body onLoad="hideMe()">
<form>
<select onChange="checkForChange()" id="selList">
    <option value="opt0" selected>Choose Option</option>
    <option value="opt1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="opt2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="opt3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="optx">Option X</option>
</select>
<BR><br>
<input type="button" value="Option 1,2,3" id="btn1">
<BR>
<input type="button" value="Option X" id="btn2">
<BR>
<input type="image" value="Click me" src="SR_@_Indian_GP.jpg" width=100 height=100 id="btn3" onClick="setMyAdd(); return false;">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** I have used 3 buttons.

First two buttons will be displayed already on page and then we will hide it.

3rd button not displayed first. After selecting option it will come.

**3rd button is as per your requirement. BUT I have added additional two incase if you want to choose that method**

Let me know if you have any queries.

Regarding **FF and IE Issue**, see example [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=158796). This example works in FF and IE both.

**Good Luck!!! Cheers!!!**

Comment: Hi Fahim Parkar 
thanks for your code.. However, when I run it, it doesnt work. when I select any option the 3rd button doesnt show up and even the other 2 buttons dont open up the page.pls check : http://uniquorn.com/form-1.html 
I really dont need the other two buttons,, I only need to make that 3rd button (click me) work..
Can you check what seems to be wrong? thanks!

Comment: try in mozilla and let me knw... give me ur email id... i will send u files... those are working on my end

Comment: first two button won't do any action.. they are just for hiding and showing purpose...

Comment: Hi fahim ok email is jamx551@yahoo.com.

Oh yeah its working in FF.. how come it doesnt in IE?

Also instead of the regular button what if I use a custom button (image)?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: first check with normal button... if we succeed we can add image too at later part... adding image is not a big deal..

Comment: ok, we can resolve that later... now can we work on image in button?

Comment: also accept my answer if you feel that I gave you correct answer... Get back to you about image shortly

Comment: sure... also can the default choice of the drop be something like "Pls choose..." ? 
because right now the default is "option 1"

Comment: well I think the IE issue and the button is just the thing I need then I can accept the answer.. thanks again

Comment: okay, I will add please choose too... also checking for image in button.. gimme 15 mins

Comment: ok thanks my friend.. 
I created another question for that pls check and you can answer in my other question about the IE issue and the button so you have 2 correct answers in a row.. thanks again

Comment: I have updated the code and sent the same on email... For hide in IE, I have sent another file. Check that and apply the same.

Comment: accept the answer... i will reply there too... give me the link of ur question... i will reply there

Comment: still not working in IE but its working in FF

also what's myFile for?

Comment: link to other question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952835/how-come-this-code-doesnt-work-in-ie-also-the-button-should-be-image-button-and

Comment: myFile is main file where buttons and image is there... check.html is the file which will work in FF and IE both... try to implement that in myFile.html and get done...

u earlier accepted, but again didn't accepted

Comment: added `<option value="opt0" selected>Choose Option</option>` as per your new requirement...

Answer (score 0):

Your lack of code in the question warrants lack of code in the response.

You will, however, want to set the `onchange` event of the [select element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp).